# How does bcrypt "know" whether a given hash is associated with a given password?

Tags: encryption, hash, mapping, bcrypt, password-encryption

Given a password `P` and hash `H`, the function `bcrypt.compare(P, H)` tells you whether or not `H` is a bcrypt hash of `P`.

**Question:** How does `bcrypt.compare` do the above? It's mysterious to me since `P` may be associated with many different hashes, and `bcrypt` itself doesn't seem to have any "memory" of the hashes it creates for `P`.

(Bonus question: Am I right to assume that the above implies that each bcrypt hash is associated with exactly one password? Or am I wrong -- may a hash be associated with many passwords?)

Comment: bcrypt just recalculate the hash and verify against the previous hash (notice that the bcrypt hash includes the salt & cost used when originally hashed). And, yes - severel passwords will exists that give the same hash.

Answer (score 1):

Hashing:

```
string BCryptHashPassword(password) 
{
   Byte[] salt = GenerateSomeSalt();
   return DoTheHash(password, salt);
}
```

Verifying:

```
Boolean BCryptVerifyPassword(password, expectedHash)
{
   Byte[] salt = ExtractSaltFromExpectedHash(expectedHash);
   String actualHash = DoTheHash(password, salt);
   return (actualHash == expectedHash);
}
```

It hashes the password again with the original salt, and compares them.
}

Comment: As someone inexperienced in this field, I thought salts are supposed to make a password harder to recover from a given hash, so it's curious that `bcrypt` can extract salts from hashes. What is stopping malicious third-parties from extracting salts, too? Or, is it that salt extraction alone isn't enough to recover the original password, and hence isn't much of a security-risk?

Comment: @Asker Salt is, *by definition*, not secret. Salt is simply meant to be **different**. The point of salt is that nobody can use a rainbow table - they have to go through the effort of hashing every possible password, rather than looking it up in a giant table. bcrypt is nice because it generates the salt **for** you, and stores it in the resulting hash string (so you don't have to worry about storing it in a database somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

BCrypt does not only save the hash in `H` it also saves among other things the salt used to create the hash ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt#Description) a full explanation).

Match takes the raw password and the expected hash to match a password, so it simply extracts the salt from the expected hash and reapplies it to the raw password.